# Delete all children with duplicate columns except for the 1st

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which will find all children that have a duplicate column and give me a list of the ids grouped by their parent. How can I modify the query to exclude the 1st duplicate and delete the remaining?

The query I have:

```
select t2.table3id, t1.type, group_concat(t1.id) as table1ids
from table1 t1 join
   table2 t2
   on t1.id = t2.table1id
group by t2.table3id, t1.type
having count(*) > 1;
```

Query results:

```
table1Id  table1Type table3Id
   2,5      myType     1
   4,6      myType     2
```

table 1 columns

```
id
Type
```

table 2 columns

```
id
table1Id
table3Id
```

Sample Data:

```
table 1:
    id    Type
    1      aType
    2      myType
    3      myType
    4      myType
    5      myType
    6      myType

table 2:
    id    table1Id    table3Id
    1        1            1
    2        2            1
    3        4            2
    4        5            1
    5        6            2
```

I would like the query to delete table1 rows with id's 5 and 6

Comment: You're going to need to remove all of the references to table1 IDs as well in all your other tables so you don't have ID values that reference nothing.  Is that the only two places where a table1Id exists?

Comment: right. table1 and table2 are the only places where a table1Id exists